# Derivatives consider $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ using the definition

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Consider $f(x)=x+\sqrt{x}$ using the definition to compute the derivative $f'$ of $f$. Just asking: am I doing this wrong?

$$f'(a)= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}$$
$$f'(a) = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{ a+h+\sqrt{a+h} -a-\sqrt{a}}{h}$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) throughout.  It looks like you dropped part of the expression.  It should be $\lim\limits_{x\to a} \dfrac{a+h+\sqrt{a+h}-a-\sqrt a }h$

Comment: Your definition is incorrect. You're supposed to have $h \to 0$, not $x \to a$. The latter is used for the difference quotient form: $f'(a) = \lim_\limits{x \to a} \dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: apart from that is the answer right?

Comment: No, but it isn't even clear what you were doing.

Comment: It would be better if you showed all your steps so we could see where you've made any errors. Also, it seems like you treated the limit as if $h \to 0$ anyway (which is correct), so I'll edit the question.

Comment: I fixed the MathJax for the question, but it wasn't clear what you did at the end. Can you add that too? Also, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a tutorial on how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Let set $f(x)=\underbrace{x}_{f_1}+\underbrace{\sqrt{x}}_{f_2}$.

- derivative of $f_1$

$\dfrac{f_1(a+h)-f_1(a)}{h} = \dfrac{a+h-a}h = \dfrac hh = 1\to 1\quad$ so $\quad{f_1}'(a)=1$.

- derivative of $f_2$

$\dfrac{f_2(a+h)-f_2(a)}{h} = \dfrac{\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a}}h = \dfrac{(\sqrt{a+h}-\sqrt{a})(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})}$

i.e. when you have an expression $\sqrt{u} -\sqrt{v}$ multiply by conjugated quantity $\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}$ to make $u+v$ appear and the $0$ difference be resolved.

$ \cdots = \dfrac{a+h-a}{h(\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a})} = \dfrac hh\times \dfrac 1{\sqrt{a+h}+\sqrt{a}}\to \dfrac 1{2\sqrt{a}}\quad$ so $\quad{f_2}'(a)=\dfrac 1{2\sqrt{a}}$.